# Python keep rows if a specific column contains a particular value or string

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am very green in python. I have not found a specific answer to my problem searching for online resources. With that said it would be great if you could give some hints.

I have an example of df as below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'names':['Alex','Joseph','Kate'],'exam1': [90, 68, 70], 'exam2': [100, 98, 88]})

print(df)

    names  exam1  exam2
0    Alex     90    100
1  Joseph     68     98
2    Kate     70     88
```

I would like to make a for loop to iterate over the rows and if the `names` column is equal to `Joseph` and `Kate` to get a new df as below:

```
names  exam1  exam2
0  Joseph     68     98
1    Kate     70     88
```

I know there is a way like below but I would like to do it via for loop.

```
list=['Joseph','Kate']
new_df=df[df['names'].isin(list)]
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: This is a bad question with an obvious [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/871151). A for loop is just an attempted solution to your *actual problem*. I'd advice asking about the actual problem directly instead of that attempted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to use loops but this is how you'd it:

```
rows = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['names'] == 'Kate' or row['names'] == 'Joseph':
        rows.append(row)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(new_df)


    names  exam1  exam2
1  Joseph     68     98
2    Kate     70     88
```